# jQuery Simple tabs with a certain markup

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-tabs

I am wanting to make a simple jQuery tabs, this is going into a cms and uses an editor for the markup so the following markup is really what i need to have to make it easy for the end user to add them.

```
<h3>
    Title here</h3>
<h4>
    Subtitle here</h4>
<ul>
    <li>
        Menu option 1</li>
    <li>
        Menu option 2</li>
    <li>
        Menu option 3</li>
    <li>
        Menu option 4</li>
</ul>
<div>
    <p>
        Tab option 1 content</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        Tab option 2 content</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        Tab option 3 content</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        Tab option 4 content</p>
</div>
```

However im not sure how to write this custom code to achieve this, could anyone lend me a hand in doing so?

Many Thanks

Comment: not clear what custom code you are referring to....please explain problem in more detail

Comment: i want to use the following markup provided and make as tabs, the ul list being the tabs and the <div>'s being the content for each tab - want to do in jquery

Comment: numerous tabs plugins available..would help if you are more specific exactly what you can't figure out and identify clearly your issue

Comment: there are lots around however i need to write one that uses that format of markup above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOuld be simpler if you modified the html you generate from whatever editor you use when you create it. Adding classes to headings and wrapping the tabs in a main div as well as creating markup that tabs plugins would want would save additional code to change it again.

Here's a solution however that takes what you have and creates jQueryUI tabs markup:

```
var $outputContainer=$('body');

/* get basic markup from editor source*/
var editorHTML=$('#editorContent').html();

var $content=$(editorHTML);
var $headings=$content.filter(':lt(2)');

/* create a tabs  wrapper*/
var $tabs=$('<div id="tabs">').append($content.filter('h4').nextUntil() );
/* add links to tabs li's */
$tabs.children('ul').find('li').each(function( tabIdx){
    $(this).html(function(i, html){
        return '<a href="#tabs-'+tabIdx+'">'+html+'</a>';
    });
})
/* add ID to content DIV's*/
$tabs.children('div').each(function( i){
     this.id= 'tabs-'+i;
});
/* insert modifyied html in DOM*/
$outputContainer.html( $headings).append( $tabs);
/* initilaize tabs*/
$tabs.tabs();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PKLcR/)**</kbd>

Comment: That is what i want to avoid though because im not sure how to add custom classes to the style dropdown in ckeditor - it has one to wrap a empty div and do lists already you see

Comment: oh sorry, would this rewrite the markup i want into tabs markup?